# Error Linting URL: An internal error occurred while linting the URL

Tags: facebook, debugging, facebook-opengraph, lint

How to **debug** the facebook **debugger**?

Detailed description of the problem:

I use the "Open Graph Protocol In Posts and Pages" plugin to manually enter OG data for the posts on my self-hosted wordpress site. Before sharing them on Facebook, I test the post's url in the FB debugger tool and the results are always correct.

However, recently the debugger returned this error message: "Error Linting URL: An internal error occurred while linting the URL" and I can't get rid of it for days. I tried to debug again for several times, it doesn't help. It's stucked. I googled for a solution but I couldn't find any. I may be wrong, but this error message seems to be rare.

I'm not an expert, but I think that the debugger tool somehow got confused by the double OG data in my post:

1. The OG info that I manually inserted into the plugin "Open Graph
   Protocol In Posts and Pages".
2. The OG info automatically generated
   by the JWPLayer wordpress plugin when a video is inserted into the
   post.

I need the first one only, I ussualy delete the JWPlayer's custom fields, but this time I forgot to do that.

After the debugger returned an error message, I deleted the JWP custom fields, hoping that they caused some conflict, I saved the post and tried to debug again. The debugger returned the error message again.

The Graph API sees outdated information about my post and it won't flush it, though I corrected everything in my post and I debugged several times afterwards. It seems to me, that the debugger saw an error in my url and won't forget it.

I even deleted the post, copied and pasted its content to a new post and gave it the same title (losing those visitors who may follow the short permalink but anyway). The debugger reacts the same way to the republished post. Error message again. I tested my other posts in the debugger, everything is perfect. its obvious that the debugger remembered this particular url for something. If I republish the post under a different  title in the url, the problem will go away.

I shared that problematic url to Facebook and strangely it shows correct data. Everything seems OK: title, description, thumbnail etc... However, I tested the share button in my post and it displays the wrong data on Facebook, though I corrected it already. The debugger sees data which is not in the post anymore. for that reason, I was forced to remove the share button, so the visitors would not share wrong info on Facebook.

Now I'm in a paradoxal situation, trying to find a way to **debug the debugger**. How to flush its memory so it can forget my url and I can have a fresh start from zero?

As you see, I'm not an expert in these matters. I spent enormous time and resources to build my site without any previous knowledge of php and css and now everything goes to hell because of these facebook bugs. I'm losing precious time dealing with this nonsence. Why everything must be so complicated? I ask all the developers, please make one good, simple, user-friendly and working standard and stick to it. Please stop complicating. What is this error message now? The debugger offers absloutely no explanation and no solution. Instead of sloving problems, its stucked and became a problem itself. The only thing that one can do is to wait hoping that the error will go away by itself. This is a pure nonsence.

ADDITIONAL DETAILS:

**This is what the Graph API sees in my url. Though that data is not valid anymore, the debugger still remembers it. You can see the video OG automatically inserted by the JWPLayer plugin:**

```
{
   "url": "http://mydomain/post-title/",
   "type": "video.movie",
   "title": "",
   "image": [
      {
         "url": "http://mydomain/uploads-folder/post-title-video-thumbnail.jpg"
      },
      {
         "url": "http://mydomain/uploads-folder/post-thumbnail.jpg"
      }
   ],
   "video": [
      {
         "url": "http://mydomain/uploads-folder/jw-player-plugin-for-wordpress/player/player.swf?file=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fmydomain\u00252Ffiles\u00252Fvideo-title.flv&controlbar=bottom&dock=false&autostart=false&height=331&width=545&captions.back=false&captions.fontsize=12&captions.state=true&icons=true&playlist.position=none&playlistsize=180&repeat=none&shuffle=false&bufferlength=1&smoothing=true&stretching=uniform&wmode=opaque&mute=false&volume=90&plugins=captions-1\u00252Cgapro-2\u00252C&gapro.accountid=UA-76476476476-1&gapro.trackstarts=true&gapro.trackpercentage=true&gapro.tracktime=true",
         "type": "application/x-shockwave-flash",
         "width": 545,
         "height": 331
      }
   ],
   "description": "",
   "site_name": "here's the name",
   "updated_time": "2012-12-05T20:09:40+0000",
   "id": "754654658476545"
```

**And this is what the debugger should see now after the corrections, but it fails to do so. However, it shows correctly when the url is pasted in Facebook:**

```
{
   "url": "http://mydomain/post-title/",
   "type": "website",
   "title": "here's the title",
   "image": [
      {
         "url": "http://mydomain/uploads-folder/post-thumbnail.jpg"
      }
   ],
   "description": "This is a story about...",
   "site_name": "my site",
   "updated_time": "2012-12-05T20:11:56+0000",
   "id": "754654658476545"
}
```

**When shared through a button, it shows the previous, wrong data.**

Comment: If it's any consolation, I'm having exactly the same problem. Could you post the real URL to the page and I'll see if I can help?

Comment: The url under the `video` key of the json representation is broken as all instances of the percent sign have been substituted by the unicode code point reference ( ie. `\u0025` instead of `%`). however, this syntax is not defined for urls, thus your url will not be interpreted correctly without some js layer substituting in reverse.

Comment: Please post the URL so I can run it through Facebook's internal systems and try and debug.

Comment: At the bottom there is link "See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL" If the data there is wrong, monitor your web application to identify why the data is wrong. Check "Time Scraped" is updating when clicking "Fetch new scrape information" If it is, I would monitor the traffic coming to/from web server of URL you are providing.

Comment: Down voting, no URL provided for investigation.

Comment: Is there a reason you do not mention the available "Fetch new scrape information" and "Show existing scrape information" buttons? This all sounds like a simple cache issue. If you make changes to a post afterwards and just paste the URL again FB will take the cached information in most cases and you have to explicitly hit the "Fetch new scrape information" button in the debugger to get the updated content.

Answer (score 1):

Force the Facebook crawler to re-fetch your data:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects#update

> The Facebook crawler will re-scrape (and therefore update) objects:
>
> When the object URL is input in the Object Debugger Every 30 days
>   after the first scrape When an app triggers a scrape using an API
>   endpoint This Graph API endpoint is simply a call to:
>
> `POST /?id={object-instance-id or object-url}&amp;scrape=true`
>
> The id parameter can be either the canonical URL of your object or the
>   ID of the object instance in the graph.